# Fixed sidebar menu hover not visible when scrollable

Tags: css

We have a site under development. The menu bar is fixed to the left hand side of the page. When the window size is reduced to a height of approx 700px, parts of the menu are no longer visible, so we need to make this scrollable vertically.

When we add

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

to .main-header the area is now scrollable, but the hover over sub-menu's are cut off. [image: Image showing the hover over sub-menu being cut off]

Any help greatly appreciated. The development site is here: http://washingtongroup.sbcomms-dev.co.uk/

Comment: We cannot try to help you if you do not share your code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the URL to the dev site. I usually add code to the questions, but not sure what to add here as there is so much going on..

Comment: Property Overflow hide the content who exceeds the height and width.
I think you must resize the width of your submenu box.

But, without your code, i can't say anymore.

Comment: Will this help? http://codepen.io/sbcomms/pen/yJNVaV

Comment: Have you try a z-index on your submenu boxes ?

Comment: I have tried adding z-index properties to the sub-menu's and that hasn't helped.

Comment: Even in your Javascript ??

Comment: I haven't tried any modifications to the Javascript. TBH I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: I've updated codepen.io/sbcomms/pen/yJNVaV so it now scrolls again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be arising because your container is set to overflow-y scroll and your overflow-x is hidden, which is making your hover state clip on the horizontal. To avoid this you need to set your overflox-x to visible BUT according to the W3c: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’. The computed value of ‘overflow’ is equal to the computed value of ‘overflow-x’ if ‘overflow-y’ is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’.

So in effect, if you are using visible for either overflow-x or overflow-y and something other than visible for the other. The visible value is interpreted as auto, which is in turn creating the clipping.

It seems to me you have to implement a different layout strategy, as your header area is **position:fixed** with a defined width. If I were you I would set the 'header' area back to position static and let the menu scroll with the rest of the page.

Here is a visualization to see more context to show that the current approach you have will not work without drastically changing your layout approach:

http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html